# android google map markers dont shown

Tags: java, android, google-maps, dictionary, google-maps-markers

My application heve 3 tabs, one of tabs contain google map. When I start my application, I see map, I can zoom and move on map, but I don't see crated markers on it.

Maps activity have auto generated code:

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
```

Comment: "one of tabs contain google map"
"Maps activity have auto generated code". 
Do you have two maps ? one is in tab and other is in activity ?

Comment: Activity contaions 3 tabs. One of activity have map and this map don't show markers.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have enabled maps for android in `Google API Console`. Check if you have followed all the steps mentioned in the  [Official Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start#step_3_create_a_google_maps_project). Your activity must extend `FragmentActivity` and to initialize GoogleMap object. Make sure you have added support library.

Try to create a map with this line:

```
MapFragment mMapFragment=MapFragment.newInstance(mapOptions());
```